# FlowLayout of UICollectionView and reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My app crashes when I use FlowLayout object in the code and call reloadData() on CollectionView object. I do not have such exception when I use standard FlowLayout (settings from XCode).

This is how I use FlowLayout to calculate section's inset depending on device width.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minItemSpacing
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = minItemSpacing

    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: headerHeight)

    let containerWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    if (containerWidth < 350) {
        inset = 2
    }
    else if (containerWidth >= 350 && containerWidth < 400) {
        inset = 10
    }
    else {
        inset = 14
    }
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: minItemSpacing, left: inset, bottom: minItemSpacing, right: inset)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

with such code app starts normally, but when I go from another view controller to main where CollectionView is used and collectionView.reloadData() is called

```
@IBAction func saveMyObjects(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let myObjectsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? MyObjectsViewController {
        MyObjects.Objects.removeAll()
        MyObjects.Objects.appendContentsOf(myObjectsViewController.MyObjects)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

app crashes with the following exception.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

If I comment

```
// collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

line to use values from XCode, app works without exception.

Additional code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ObjectCollectionViewCell
    // Configure the cell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: Groups[indexPath.section].Objects[indexPath.row].Image)
    cell.label.text = Groups[indexPath.section].Objects[indexPath.row].Name
    if (Groups[indexPath.section].Objects[indexPath.row].Image != "") {
        cell.label.hidden = true
        cell.imageView.hidden = false
    }
    else {
        cell.imageView.hidden = true
        cell.label.hidden = false
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you post your crash stackTrace? to see what is happen?

Comment: Hello,*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182afedb0 0x182163f80 0x1829dedfc 0x1884bcf80 0x1884b95e4 0x1884ba254 0x187de5394 0x187de4870 0x100112048 0x1001121c8 0x187c50224 0x1855e2994 0x1855dd5d0 0x1855dd490 0x1855dcac0 0x1855dc820 0x1855d5de4 0x182ab4728 0x182ab24cc 0x1829dcc70 0x187cc394c 0x187cbe088 0x10013d8fc 0x18257a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @ReinierMelian XCode shows problem in "14 start", if I click on it, following information appears libdyld.dylib`start:
    0x18257a8b4 <+0>: nop    
    0x18257a8b8 <+4>: bl     0x1825b534c               ; exit
    0x18257a8bc <+8>: brk    #0x3

Comment: Can you post your code for `internal func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I added All Exceptions break point, now XCode shows problem in line collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

Comment: @ReinierMelian posted additional code (delegate method). What does mean context? This line in my first code block inside viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: I think that i have your answer, I will to share with you in few moments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after to review your code so many times, I think that your problem is that you should remove the code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and implement the methods existing on `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to do what you need,

```
optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize

optional public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

I think if you implement this methods and remove your code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` your code will work as you need, Is highly discouraged to do that with your approach ;), I hope this helps you